# Prerequisites for ROS

Tags: ros, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going to start learning ROS but before I start, I'll learn python. What should I learn in python?
I don't have any experience in Linux or ubunto. What do I need to know? I found many versions of ROS (indigo Igloo- Kinetic kame - Lunar loggerhead) What is the best to download? Any other advices?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282617/prerequisites-for-ros/) by [ZeyadTh](https://answers.ros.org/users/33695/zeyadth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The most basic ROS tutorials don't really require any specific knowledge about C++/Python or Ubuntu Linux, but familiarity with Ubuntu Linux at least is highly recommended. To complete the tutorials you really only need to know how to open the terminal in Ubuntu and follow instructions:

https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials#Core_ROS_Tutorials

Going beyond the tutorials and even understanding what they're teaching will require more knowledge of Python and/or C++/CMake.

I also recommend reading the conceptual overview, or at least going back to it frequently to help you understand the core concepts:

https://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Introduction

As for which version of ROS to use, please see:

https://wiki.ros.org/Distributions#Which_distribution_to_use

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
@ZeyadTh: you might also be interested in the [ROS Industrial Training Exercises](http://ros-industrial.github.io/industrial_training). It says 'industrial', but the first few chapters are all about ROS in general and it includes a Linux fundamentals section.

No Python though.